npx looking for modules in incorrect directory
I'm trying to run the following command in my bash terminal (all through VS Code):
$ npx tsc with-typescript.ts

When I run this command, however, I get the following error:
The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\joshu\Programming Projects\Udemy Courses\typescript\bin\tsc'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1186:15)        
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.2.0

I've run 'npm init -y' and 'npm install typescript', and it properly created the package.json file and node_modules folder in my project folder (~/Programming Projects/Udemy Courses/Python & React/Web Development Bootcamp/React js Practice/typescript-practice). But for some reason npx seems to be looking in the wrong directory for the typescript module, since a 'typescript' folder doesn't even exist in the 'Udemy Courses' folder.
I've tried deleting package.json, package-lock.json and the node_modules folder; uninstalling and reinstalling node.js; looking into whether the npm prefix might be the issue (which isn't the case, as the prefix is properly set to the project root folder). At this point I'm just not sure what to try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hello hope your doing well,
i had this issue as well from no where and it was looking also outside the path of workspace which in my case was %appdata% npm.
i've been in this issue for like 2 hours idk what happened everything was working normal
i used Rev Uninstaller and removed Node and all reg files and all traces reinstalled same problem tried every single fix possible on stackoverflow and github nothing worked
i even did a system restore point at the end i fixed it but i was like confused/angry of how silly it was
just copy ur package.json to the your directory that it says it's missing in your case "C:\Users\joshu\Programming Projects\Udemy Courses" and just run npm install that did it for me
hope it works for you

This answer really only needs a couple of sentences, one on copying that JSON file and one on re-running npm.
